# Convert XML to HTML using XSLT Pagination

Tags: html, xml, xslt, pagination

I know there are some questions about this here, and I tried a lot of solutions around but i'm still stuck.
I tried to use this [pagination in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235060/pagination-in-xsl)
and this [Possible to split XML into multiple pages with XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858057/possible-to-split-xml-into-multiple-pages-with-xslt) but don't get what I need,

I need to create a pagination in my generated html, using a XML through a XSLT parser.

XML file is like this

```
<root>
    <result>
        <a>field one</a>
        <b>field two</b>
        <c>field three</c>
    </result>
    <result>
        <a>hello</a>
        <b>thanks</b>
        <c>for help</c>
    </result>
    <result>
        <a>thank</a>
        <b>you</b>
        <c>!!</c>
    </result>
    ..... 
</root>
```

and my XSLT without pagination is this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">


    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">
                    <xsl:for-each select="result">
                        <div class="list_item">
                            <div class="dmv_line">
                                <div class="box_text">
                                    <h2><xsl:value-of select="a"/></h2>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dmv_line">
                                    <div class="box_text">
                                        <h2><xsl:value-of select="b"/></h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dmv_line">
                                    <div class="box_text">
                                        <h2><xsl:value-of select="c"/></h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I need is to create a `<div>` that encapsulate results 3 by 3 or 4 by 4, which I will make hide or visible in javascript later.. 
Thanks

[EDIT]:
The HTML output, if I assume to make pagination 2 elements per page, and considering only the 3 elements in example, the output should be

```
<-- page number one --->
<div id="1">
 <div class="list_item">
     <div class="dmv_line">
        <div class="box_text">
            <h2>field one</h2>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="dmv_line">
        <div class="box_text">
            <h2>field two</h2>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="dmv_line">
        <div class="box_text">
            <h2>field three</h2>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
     <div class="list_item">
         <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
                <h2>hello</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
                <h2>thanks</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
                <h2>for help</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <-- END OF page number one --->
 <-- page number two --->
<div id="2">     
     <div class="list_item">
         <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
                <h2>thank</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
                <h2>you</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
                <h2>!!!</h2>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>  
 <-- END OF page number two --->
```

Comment: It would help if you gave a sample of the html you are expecting to output when you have pagination. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problems like this, the approach is to firstly select the elements that will occur first on each of your 'pages'. This is achieved by checking its position.

```
<xsl:for-each select="result[position() mod $size = 1]">
```

So, if the **$size** variable is set to 2, this would select the **result** elements in positions 1, 3, 5, etc...

Within this loop, you can then output the containing **div** tag for the 'age'

```
<div id="{position()}">
```

Note that position is context-sensitive, and will return the position of the node in the node set you have just selected (i.e. it will return 1, 2, 3, etc)

Finally, to get the **result** elements that make up the 'page' you can select them like so

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $size]" />
```

And the template that matches them would effectively be like your existing code in the **xsl:for-each**.

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:param name="size" select="2"/>

   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:for-each select="result[position() mod $size = 1]">
         <div id="{position()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $size]"/>
         </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="result">
      <div class="list_item">
         <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
               <h2>
                  <xsl:value-of select="a"/>
               </h2>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
               <h2>
                  <xsl:value-of select="b"/>
               </h2>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="dmv_line">
            <div class="box_text">
               <h2>
                  <xsl:value-of select="c"/>
               </h2>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should hopefully give you the output you need.

As an aside, you have a bit of code repetition in your code. Try replacing the template that matches **result** with these two templates instead:

```
<xsl:template match="result">
   <div class="list_item"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="a|b|c" />
   </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="result/*">
      <div class="dmv_line">
         <div class="box_text">
            <h2>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </h2>
         </div>
       </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
work perfect.
And also thanks for your aside solution, but my html have more class beside the "box_text", I just give a shorter example :)
+1 before I tried, and accept answer when checked is ok!

Thanks again